# Jquery toggle icon up and down function

Tags: jquery, html

If I click the content in `.accordion-head` the arrow image should be changed as 'up' while the content in `.accordion-body` is slid up. I think I have wrapped the content with the right `div` tag, but it did not work. Can anyone help me and figure it out?

```js
$('.accordion').each(function() {
  var $accordian = $(this);
  $accordian.find('.accordion-head').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    $accordian.find('.accordion-body').slideUp();
    if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
      $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 850px;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  /*height:500px;*/
  /*color:white;*/
  /*margin-top:50px;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 35px !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

hr.garo {
  border: 1px solid #757272;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

#tableMain {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: white;
}

.page {
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#pop {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#bor {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pay {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.418);
}

.breakrow {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

input {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#sep {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#space {
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow {
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top-color: lightgray;
}

.breakrow-head.open .arrow {
  margin-top: 11px;
  border-bottom-color: #F3F3F3;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <span class="title">예약 내역 조회</span>
  <hr class="garo">
  <br><br>
  <table id="tableMain" class="accordion">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>예약 번호</th>
        <th>대여 기간</th>
        <th>지점명</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <div class="accordion-head">
        <tr class="breakrow">
          <td>
            <div class="arrow down"></div> 1</td>
          <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
          <td>강남지점-강남지점<input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""> </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="20">
            <table id="sep">
              <tbody>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" rowspan="5" colspan="3"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" colspan="12">차량 대여요금</td>
                  <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" colspan="12">보험료</td>
                  <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" colspan="12">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                  <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor" colspan="12">총 결제 금액</td>
                  <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-head">
        <tr class="breakrow">
          <td>
            <div class="arrow down"></div> 1</td>
          <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
          <td>강남지점-강남지점<input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""> </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="20">
            <table id="sep">
              <tbody>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" rowspan="5" colspan="3"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg">
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" colspan="12">차량 대여요금</td>
                  <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" colspan="12">보험료</td>
                  <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td id="bor" colspan="12">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                  <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pop">
                  <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor" colspan="12">총 결제 금액</td>
                  <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just some modify into your HTML structure because of you can not insert `div` element out of `<tr>` element so follow html standard structure.
Follow below snippet, I hope this will help you lot.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-head', function(){
  $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open');
  if (!$(this).hasClass('open')){
    $(this).addClass('open'); 
  }
  else{
    $('.accordion-head').removeClass('open'); 
    $(this).addClass('close'); 
  }
  $('.accordion-body').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideDown(); 
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 850px;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  /*height:500px;*/
  /*color:white;*/
  /*margin-top:50px;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 35px !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

hr.garo {
  border: 1px solid #757272;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

#tableMain {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: white;
}

.page {
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#pop {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#bor {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pay {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.418);
}

.breakrow {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

input {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#sep {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#space {
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow {
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top-color: lightgray;
  transition: 350ms;
  position: absolute;
}
.accordion-head.open{
  background: #eee;
}
.accordion-head.open .arrow {
  margin-top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  <span class="title">예약 내역 조회</span>
  <hr class="garo">
  <br><br>
  <table id="tableMain" class="accordion">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>예약 번호</th>
        <th>대여 기간</th>
        <th>지점명</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- Number #1 -->
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td><div class="arrow"></div> 1</td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점<input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="5" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Number #2 -->
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td><div class="arrow"></div> 2</td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점<input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="5" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Number #3 -->
      <tr class="accordion-head breakrow open">
        <td><div class="arrow"></div> 3</td>
        <td>2020.02.05 ~ 2020.02.07</td>
        <td>강남지점-강남지점<input id="space" type="button" value="예약 취소" onclick=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion-body">
        <td colspan="3">
          <table id="sep">
            <tbody>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor" rowspan="5" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201509/925979_306258_1646.jpg"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">차량 대여요금</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">보험료</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td id="bor">쿠폰/이벤트</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid gray">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="pop">
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;" id="bor">총 결제 금액</td>
                <td style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;">52,520원</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```